# Unlock 3rd party transceivers on Arista switches

Tags: arista

Is there a way to unlock third-party transceivers on an Arista DCS-7050QX-32S-F running version 4.24.0F? I've experimented with a few widely-recognized solutions, but it appears they're no longer effective

Answer (score 2):

Older EOS version query a 'magic' file for unlocking 3rd-party modules: create/touch `/mnt/flash/enable3px` to trigger.

Newer versions require `service unsupported-transceiver` plus a license key that you need to obtain from your Arista account manager. Don't try support as it won't work.

Afaik, both methods require you to save the config and reboot the switch, then reinsert the module.

Comment: Well, that would certainly deter me from wanting to buy Arista switches. Yikes.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer Then Arista isn't the only brand you can't buy. Vendor lock-in is poorly documented - sadly but for obvious reasons - so it requires some research on your part. It's understandable from the support POV but doesn't need to be tolerated when there's no option to disable - go elsewhere. Another option is to buy 3rd-party, faked modules (which I used to do practically always).

Comment: Yeah, I know it is common practice to make a bit of a hill to climb to use 'unbranded' transceivers but the 'talk to your account manager' part is the shocker for me. That need for a license key and a reboot is a kick right in the teeth. Give me a scary disclaimer about support/warranty and send me on my merry way! Especially when, as you say, you can get transceivers that are easily faked anyway. It's just hostile to the customer for no real benefit to anyone but the manufacturer (and I would say limited benefit to them).